# Tig doesn't display colors at all

Tags: git, tig

I'm trying to work with tig to see git database. But it doesn't display colors at all. If I try to set a color in ~/.tigrc it just ignores it.
I added a binding and it works, so tig do see my tigrc file.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Do regular git commands like `git status` or `git log` display in colour? What is the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: I'm glad this helped you. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, command line applications rely on the value of your `$TERM` environment variable to determine whether your system supports coloured output. A setting of `vt100` like you have does not indicate colour support.

There are many possible settings for this variable, though a common "base" setting that supports 16 colours is `xterm`. The way to change this setting will depend on your shell, but in Bash you can try this:

```
# Set the new value for the current session
export TERM=xterm

# Now test tig...

# If successful, add to your .bashrc for future sessions
echo export TERM=xterm >> ~/.bashrc
```

[This section](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-TERM-variable.html) from the GNU gettext manpage that discusses some other possible settings for the `$TERM` variable.